# executing a bat file in C:\ProgramData in nodejs

Tags: node.js, path, process, electron, child-process

The project I'm working on is a Nodejs + Electron application.
I'm trying to execute a bat file located in

`C:\ProgramData\ApplicationSettings`

using `const exec = require('child_process').exec;`

I could execute the file just fine before i opted to move them to the programdata folder and try to execute it from there.

The code I was trying to use was

`exec(path.join(String(process.env.programdata)+'/applicationSettings/', 'command.bat'))`

Is this a path problem I am having or is it the fact that ProgramData is hidden? Is there any way for me to execute the bat file from my project?

Comment: So what isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? Also, if you're using `path.join()` don't concatenate strings with `a+'/'+b`. The `path` module will do it for you. Simply pass all path steps as separate arguments. Can you then please verify that the path produced is indeed the correct one?

Comment: By console logging, I get `C:\ProgramData\applicationSettings\command.bat`, which I can confirm that the correct path is accessed, but the bat file is never executed. It does not return any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Add function to see console output.

```
exec(..., (err, stdout, stderr)=>console.log(err?{err}:{stdout}))
```

And things should become clearer.
Haven't you been mistaken in folder 'applicationsettings'? I have 'applicationData' on my Win10 and the access to it is restricted by default...

Comment: I have already error handling, but it's not returning errors. 

applicationSettings is just a folder I created in programData that contains the bat file I want to execute.

I am already reading from a file in the same folder, which works just fine.

Comment: Do you have console output of stdout? What info do you receive after starting script?

Comment: Turns out I had closed a bracket early and that's why nothing was happening! Feel stupid

Comment: Don't, pretty usual case. It's just one more step forward!